# Laravel issue with loginUsingId (Manual Authentication)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to implement a **single signon on multiple domains**. The concept is pretty simple i.e to send unique user tokens and then verify these tokens to find the user and then log him in.

Now after verifying the token and then grabbing the user, i do something like this

```
$loggedInUser = Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, true);
```

Now i have a custom middleware where it first checks for a logged in user, i.e

```
Auth::Check()
```

The above works fine for the first time. But on refresh Auth::check() is not validated. I have also tried using all different session drivers but still doesn't work.

I used a similar code on laravel 5.2, and it did work. But on laravel 5.3 its not validating on persistent requests.

**Edit: Let me show you my Code**
I have not modified AuthServiceProvider or any other guard. I do have the user model inside a directory but i have modified the path in auth.php.

Here is the route that domain1 points to:

http://domain2.com/{{$role}}/{{$route}}/singlesignon/{{$token}}

This is then picked up by verifySingleSignOn method inside the loginController which takes in the role, route that the user came in from other domain and the token. The user is then redirected to the same routes, but on domain2. Here i can successfully recieve the user id before manually logging in.

```
public function verifySingleSignOn($role, $route, $token)
    {
        // Fetch Single Signon
        $userRepository = new UserRepository();
        $user = $userRepository->checkForSingleSignOnToken($token, ['id']);

        // Check if Token Exists
        if (isset($user->id) && is_int($user->id) && $user->id != 0) {

            // Manually Logging a user (Here is successfully recieve the user id)
            $loggedInUser = Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);

            if (!$loggedInUser) {
                // If User not logged in, then Throw exception
                throw new Exception('Single SignOn: User Cannot be Signed In');
            }
            $redirectTo = $role . '/' . $route;
            return redirect($redirectTo);
        } else {
            return Auth::logout();
        }
    }
```

Then i have this GlobalAdminAuth middleware

```
   // Check if logged in
    if( Auth::Check() ){
        $user = Auth::User();

        // Check if user is active and is a globaladmin
        if( !$user->isGlobalAdmin() || !$user->isActive() ){
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }else{
        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }

    return $next($request);
```

Now the first time everything works fine and the user moves through the middleware successfully . but the second time the else statement is triggered.

**Edit: Code for checkForSingleSignOnToken**

```
public function checkForSingleSignOnToken($token, $columns = array('*'))
{
    return User::where('single_signon', $token)->first($columns);
}
```

Comment: What is your session  driver?

Comment: I have tried all of them except redis.

Comment: Please show the code of the method `checkForSingleSignOnToken`

Comment: Are all domains on the same server? Are all domains using the same DB?

Comment: @DiogoGomes yes all the domains are using the same application which is located on a single server. The application does have multiple databases for different stuff but 'yes' all users are located in a single database.

Comment: @omerFarooq if that's the case, I don't think you need this solution. Laravel's standard authentication doesn't work for you?

Comment: Did you save your token in db so that you can check whether this token is valid or not?

Answer (score 6):

try

> `Auth::login($user);`

instead of

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are restricted domain-wise. Your application on `domain1.com` wont be able to grab cookies set by `domain2.com`.

You should be customizing the guard to use some other mechanism than cookies. Maybe use a token in the query parameters.

Comment: To me this is the heart of the problem IMO. Also faced some difficulties trying to log in manually from http://locahost:8000.

Answer (score 2):

add this to your `protected $middleware` array in `app\Http\Kernel.php`

```
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class
```

I think it has to do with an update in the framework

Answer (score 0):

no using auth:check in middleware

using request->user() or auth::user()

Answer (score 0):

> Please review bellow code structure, i had made manual authentication
>   in laravel 5.0.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('login_user_by_id/{id?}', ['as' => 'login_user_by_id', 'uses' => 'UsersController@login_user_by_id']);
Route::post('user_login_post_for_admin',['as'=>'user_login_post_for_admin','uses'=>'LoginController@user_login_post_for_admin']);
Route::get('user_logout', ['as' => 'user_logout', 'uses' => 'UsersController@user_logout']);
```

**LoginController.php**

```
public function user_login_post_for_admin(){
    $this->set_email($_POST['email']);
    $this->set_password($_POST['password']);
    $this->set_login_requested_role(['Admin','Moderator']);
    return $this->user_login_post();
}

public function user_login_post(){
    $User = new User();

    if(isset($this->email) && !empty($this->email)){
        $User->set_email(trim($this->email));
        $User->set_password(Hash::make(trim($this->password)));
        $user_login_data = $User->check_email_password_for_login();
        if(isset($user_login_data) && !empty($user_login_data)){
            if (Hash::check(trim($this->password), $user_login_data[0]->password)) {
                $response['user_id']=$user_login_data[0]->id;
                $response['name']=$user_login_data[0]->name;
                $response['surname']=$user_login_data[0]->surname;
                $response['profile_picture']=$user_login_data[0]->profile_picture;
                $response['SUCCESS']='True';
                $response['MESSAGE']='Login Success.';
                return Redirect::route('login_user_by_id',[$user_login_data[0]->id]);
            }else{
                Session::put('SUCCESS','FALSE');
                Session::put('MESSAGE', 'Invalid Credential.');
                return redirect()->back();
            }
        }else{
            Session::put('SUCCESS','FALSE');
            Session::put('MESSAGE', 'Invalid Credential.');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }else{
        Session::put('SUCCESS','FALSE');
        Session::put('MESSAGE', 'Invalid Credential.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

**UsersController.php**

```
public function login_user_by_id($id=''){
    if(isset($_GET['id'])&&!empty($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    }
    $User = new User();
    $Log=new Log();
    $user_for_auth = $User->find($id);
    Auth::login($user_for_auth, true);

    $User->id=AUTH::user()->id;
    $auth_user_role=$User->auth_user_role();
    $rl_title=$auth_user_role[0]->rl_title;

    return Redirect::route('admin_home');

}

public function user_logout(User $user){
    $User=new User();
    $login_user_id = AUTH::user()->id;
    $User->id=AUTH::user()->id;
    $auth_user_role=$User->auth_user_role();
    $login_user_role=$auth_user_role[0]->rl_title;
    $response['user_id']=$login_user_id;
    $response['SUCCESS']='TRUE';
    $response['MESSAGE']='Successfully Logout.';
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::route('admin_login');
}
```